# Is the verb "violate" idiomatic for "right"?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

> I have right to know that information. But they **violated** my right to
>   that information.

When someone does not satisfy someone's right, could we say they *violate* her right? Is that verb idiomatic in such context?

Answer (score 1):

That is a common usage. For example:

> Gatti, as far as I'm concerned, has violated my right not to know, while Ferrante protected it.

(Deborah Orr, writing in the Guardian)